# Grails 2 upgrade issues

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I'm having trouble with running grails 2 on my Linode (running ubuntu 11.10).

I can run 1.3.7 just fine, but when I try to use grails 2 the console doesn't work.  I can use grails interactive mode just fine in 1.3.7.  Grails 2 just dies.

Has anyone else seen something like this?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, there is a discussion here:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-Upgrade-issue-td4364841.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are doing development on Linode? Check your JVM version ja JAVA_HOME setting. Very old 1.6.0 releases (pre 1.6.0_18?) don't work for Grails 2.0 development. OpenJDK might cause problems too. Get the latest Oracle JavaSE 1.6.0 release (currently 1.6.0_30). The default settings in Grails 2.0 development mode requires 1GB free memory. This can be adjusted by the GRAILS_OPT environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 versions of Grails (1.22 and 2.00 ) on my 512mb VM running Ubuntu, is your GRAILS_HOME variable setup to point to the version that you want to use? What does grails help tell you in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded my project from grails 1.3.7 to grails 2.0 via STS (Spring Tool Suite) and as far as I remember, I needed to upgrade from Groovy 1.7 to Groovy 1.8 so you can check if you have Groovy 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I run unit tests in 2.0.1 and 1.3.7

2.0.1 time:
Completed 414 unit tests, 0 failed in 185855ms

1.3.7 time:
Tests Completed in 87680ms ...

java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)

I run both in command line.